# How to retrieve metadata from image file in Android

Tags: android, image, metadata

How can I retrieve metadata information such as format (jpeg, bmp, png, ..), width, height etc. from image files in Android environment?

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the width, height, and MIME type of an image like this:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/path/to/imagefile.blah", opts);
    Log.i(TAG, "Mimetype:" + opts.outMimeType);
    Log.i(TAG, "Width:" + opts.outWidth);
    Log.i(TAG, "Height:" + opts.outHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try looking up the ContentValues class, contentResolver() function, and the URI class. This should have the information you need do whatever you're trying to do.