# how to fetch metadata of an image stored on an SD card of an android phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I want to know how I could fetch all the metadata associated with an image, that is stored on the SD Card of an android mobile phone.

Comment: what types of meta data do you want ?

Comment: geo location, size,type of image, name, date ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to get the geo-location, but see the following post for getting the image width, height, and mimetype:

[How to retrieve metadata from image file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928660/how-to-retrieve-metadata-from-image-file-in-android)

You can also get the file's last modified date with the following:

```
new Date(file.lastModified())
```